# For what values of $a$ the number $1/a$ has a finite decimal representation?

Tags: limits, fractions

I think is just for $a=2^p5^q$, with $p,q\geq 0 $ but I haven't a proof. 
In particular, the exercise says:

"Let $N$ be a natural number and $S_N=\{a\in \mathbb{N} \; :\; 1\leq a \leq N \; , \; 1/a\; \text{has a finite decimal representation}\}$. Compute 
$\displaystyle\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{\vert S_N \vert}{\log^2N}$, where $\vert \cdot \vert$ is the cardinal number of a set.

If is true that $1/a$ has a finite decimal representation iff $a=2^p 5^q $, then $2^p \leq N \leftrightarrow p\leq \frac{\log N} {\log 2}$ and $5^q \leq N \leftrightarrow q\leq \frac{\log N} {\log 5}$ and maybe for $N$ big $\vert S_N \vert \sim \frac{\log^2 N}{\log 5 \log 2 }$?

Comment: You are correct.  And you are on the right track.

Comment: If 1/a has an n- digit rep.  then 10^n*1/a is an integer so $a|10^n= 2^n5^n$ so, the only prime factors of $a$ are 2 and 5.  So that proves it.  The rest... mechanics.

Comment: Thanks fleablood, your proof of my first question is very clear. But I'm not sure about the second: For example, if $N=100$ there are $\vert\{1,2,4,8,16,32,64 \}\vert = 7$ powers of 2 and $\vert \{1,5,25 \} \vert =3$ powers of 5 but not all the products are lower than 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac 1a = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k*10^{-k}$ has a finite representation of $n$ digits (i.e $a_n \ne 0$ $\iff$

$\frac {10^n}a = \sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k*10^{n-k}\in \mathbb Z$.  So $a|10^n$ so $a = 2^p5^q$ for some integers $p, q$.  Furthermore either $p$ or $q$ is equal to $n$.

Or in other words $a = 2^p5^q = 10^p5^{n-p}$ if $n= q$ or $a = 2^p5^q = 10^q2^{n-q}$ if $n=p$.  (And if $p=q=n$ then $a = 10^n$).

Okay... so lets say $N = 10^m$ then $S_N = \{2^p2^q|0\le p \le m; 0\le q \le m\}$ and $|S_N| = (m+1)^2$ and $\frac{|S_N|}{\log^2 N} = \frac {m^2+2m + 1}{m^2} = 1 + \frac 2m + \frac 1{m^2}$.

So $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac {|S_N|}{\log^2 N} = \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(m+1)^2}{m^2} = 1$.

Comment: Umm, that formula for $|S_N|$ isn't right - not every element of $S_{10^m}$ is necessarily a factor of $10^m$.  For example, $2^9 \in S_{1000}$.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I'll fix it sometime tomorrow.

Comment: a is in the form $10^m2^p5^q$ where either $p$ or $q$ is zero.  For $N$ there are $\sum_{k=0}^{\log_{10} N}(\log_2{\frac N{10^k}} + 1)(\log_5{\frac N{10^k}} + 1)$ such terms (rounded) that are less than N.  With paper and pencil one can probably work it all out.